# Lightning Page (FlexiPage) deployment error: Invalid property [token] in component [tableau:tableauViz]

Tags: deployment-error

I was deploying a change to a Lightning record page where I had added a Tableau View component into an accordion component

[image]

- Worked fine in my Dev org
- Deployed successfully into my Integration org
- Failed to deploy into my Staging org

  ```
  Invalid property [token] in component [tableau:tableauViz]
  ```

A search in [SFDC Help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389818&type=1) suggested the error could be caused by a difference in SFDC versions and references how to work around this using Change Sets. We don't use Change Sets, we use a Dev Ops pipeline based on GitHub and Gearset.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dev Org           Integration Org           Staging Org
  V60                 V60                       V59
```

So, this confirms the org difference. SFDC is known to add new properties inside the XML when a version changes.  This leads to no end of aggravation when you are developing in a preview release and need to deploy into orgs still on the current version.

For Lightning Pages, known in the Metadata API as `FlexiPage`, there is an `<itemInstance>` for the `Tableau View` component that looks like this:

```
<itemInstances>
        <componentInstance>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>customQueryParameters</name>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>debugMode</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>filterOnRecordId</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>forceRefresh</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>height</name>
                <value>600</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>showTabs</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>showToolbar</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>tabAdvancedFilter</name>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>token</name>                 <=== the problem
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>vizUrl</name>
                <value>https://tableau.mycompany.com/views/XXXXX/YYYYYY</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>tableau:tableauViz</componentName>
            <identifier>tableau_tableauViz</identifier>
            <visibilityRule>
                <criteria>
                    <leftValue>{!$Permission.CustomPermission.MyCustomPermssion}</leftValue>
                    <operator>EQUAL</operator>
                    <rightValue>true</rightValue>
                </criteria>
            </visibilityRule>
        </componentInstance>
    </itemInstances>
```

The sub-component at issue (mentioned in the error message) is:

```
<componentInstanceProperties>
    <name>token</name>
</componentInstanceProperties>
```

Since the `token` had no value, rather than try and reconstruct the source from an org at V59, I simply edited the GitHub file and removed:

```
<componentInstanceProperties>
    <name>token</name>
</componentInstanceProperties>
```

and re-did the PR. Deployment succeeded.

Had my new feature required the use of a `token`, I would have had to wait until staging and PROD orgs were upgraded to V60.